# Is it necessary to implement a view cache for react like ionic view cache?

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework, redux

I like the view cache feature of `ionic`. If the view is cached, when navigate to other **route**, and back, the **controller** of the view cached will not **initialize** again.

In recent year, I use `react` of facebook. It's awesome.

I found that the **container component** will trigger the lifecycle `componentDidMount` again if you navigate to other route and back.

**Ok, You can control if send ajax or not in componentDidMount base on redux data cache. You can control the component re-render or not by shouldComponentUpdate too.**

But An question comes to my mind. I think cache the view which meanings cache the data and view both which meanings the component will not trigger any lifecycle method. It sounds like a view **display** or **hidden**.

**So, Is it necessary to implement a view cache feature for react container component like ionic view cache?**

P.S *Anybody can help me edit my question correctly by correctly English XD, thanks!*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

React bases component instance lifespans on the render output of a parent.  If a `Parent` component returns a `<Child>` component every time it renders, then React will keep the same `Child` instance alive.  If `Parent` stops rendering `<Child>`, then React will unmount and destroy the `Child` instance.

So, if you want to keep the same component instance alive, you need to keep rendering it from the parent, and do so in the same output structure.

See the [React docs on the "reconciliation algorithm"](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reconciliation.html) for more info.